# saving reports as pdf

Tags: ms-access, vba, pdf

Currently I am using pdfcreator to convert reports into pdf format. As this has to be done manually I am looking for a solution to automatically save reports as pdf files. The code should be working in access 2000 and newer versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are using [Stephen Lebans' ReportToPDF](http://www.lebans.com/reporttopdf.htm) to generate PDF files.
We use Access 2003, and it works for A2000, 2002 and 2003 (A2007 has PDF support out-of-the-box).

It consists of just two DLLs that need to be in your application folder or the `%windir%\system32` folder, and **they don't need to be registered**.

We preferred using this solution instead of a PDF printer because just copying two files is easier than installing a PDF printer on every machine.

Answer (score 1):

I've used this approach before: http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/204362-howto-automate-printing-access-reports-pdf-files

> This is the approach I used to automate printing of Microsoft Access
>   reports to PDF format i.e. unattended and without annoying "Save As..."
>   dialogs, and - more importantly - without having to use a commercial
>   program such as Adobe Acrobat and its associated API.

The technique uses Ghostscript and Redirection Port Monitor - two free
programs for creating PDF documents provided free by Russell Lang. The
actual automation requires VBA coding using the FileSystemObject,
WScript.Network (the Windows Script Host Network Object) and Access
automation.

**INSTRUCTIONS:**

1) Install Ghostscript
- An interpreter for the Postscript language and PDF
http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/

2) Install RedMon - Redirection Port Monitor
- Redirects a special printer port to a program (such as
Ghostscript)
http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/

3) Set up virtual PDF printer using Ghostscript and Redmon
- Here are two web pages that explain how to install the
above tools:
http://masterdev.dyndns.dk/know/freepdf.html
http://stat.tamu.edu/~henrik/GSWriter/GSWriter.html

4) Configure the RedMon printer port used by the PDF virtual printer in
the following mannter:
- Output: "Program handles output"
- The new PDF file should always save to the same file i.e.
C:\temp\output.pdf

Use this for the "Program Arguments" setting:
@c:\gs\pdfconf.txt -sOutputFile="C:\temp\output.pdf" -c .setpdfwrite
-f -

(Note the literal filepath instead of the "%1")

5) Write your own Visual Basic code that prints the report to the pdf
and then uses FileSystemObject to copy it to a name/location of your
chosing. Use the WScript.Network object to change the default printer
from your usual default printer to the PDF printer and back again.

Example Code (Access Visual Basic):

```
Sub PrintReportToPDF(strReport as String, _
strOutputPath as String)

Const PDF_PRINTER as String = "PDF Printer"
Const ORIGINAL_PRINTER as String = "\\OFFICE\HP1320"
Const TEMP_PATH as String = "C:\temp\output.pdf"

Dim net as WScript.Network
Dim fso as Scripting.FileSystemObject

Set net = new WScript.Network
net.setDefaultPrinter PDF_PRINTER

DoCmd.OpenReport strReport

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
fso.CopyFile TEMP_PATH, strOutputPath, True
fso.DeleteFile TEMP_PATH
Set fso = Nothing

net.setDefaultPrinter ORIGINAL_PRINTER
Set net = Nothing

End Sub
```

For the preceding code to work inside Access 2000, you have to add
references to Microsoft Scripting Runtime and Windows Script Host
Object Model.

My experience so far is that the subroutine DoCmd.OpenReport() finishes
outputting the report to PDF very quickly...however, if you have a very
large report the output.pdf might be there when the FileSystemObject
goes to move/rename it. Therefore, you might want to use the Windows
API Sleep() function.
See < http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q162150/ >

Writing a routine that prints out multiple reports is left as an
exercise to the reader. Personally, I prefer to keep my reports in a
table called "Settings_Reports" rather than hardcoding the report names
into my VBA modules.

**ADDITIONAL TIPS:**

- Use `DoCmd.SendObject()` automate the emailing of the newly-created
  reports to managers.
- Use the PDF Toolkit to merge disparate PDF reports into one file
  URL: http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk
  This can also be automated using the VBA Shell() function, or in
  VBScript via the `WScript.Shell.Run()` method
- Use VBScript to automate Access, just like Excel or Word.
  See the following Microsoft KB article:
  ACC: Using Microsoft Access as an Automation Server
  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/q147816/

Code fragment (VBScript):

```
dim acc
set acc = CreateObject("Access.Application")
with acc
..OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Reports\Sales.mdb"

' Call the customer subroutine we defined earlier
..Run("PrintReportToPDF", "rptSalesFigures_Monthly", _
"N:\Marketing\Reports\SalesSummary" _
& Year(Date()) & Format(Month(Date()),"00")

[Etc...]
```

Needless to say, there is a lot that can be done with the approach.
And the best part is that you don't have to learn another API (other
than the standard Windows Script Host and Microsoft Scripting Runtime
libraries, which you really should know anyway). And best of all it's
completely free!

**SETTING UP THE PDF PRINTER:**
Here are more detailed instructions for installing and configuring the
virtual PDF printer - cribbed from:
< http://masterdev.dyndns.dk/know/freepdf.html >

1. Install Ghostscript to C:\
   http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/AFPL/index.htm
2. Create a text file (c:\gs\pdfconf.txt) and add the following text:

   -Ic:\gs\gs8.11\lib;c:\gs\fonts
   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite
   -dNOPAUSE
   -dSAFER

Note that the first line points to version 8.11 of Ghostscript. If
you have a different version or installed it to a different
location, make the appropriate changes.

1. Download, unpack, and Install RedMon (Redirection PortMonitor)
   http://www.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/index.htm

   - When you run setup.exe you will only see a message box.
2. Go to Printers/Faxes menu under the Start button in Windows and
   add a new printer.

   - The driver for the printer must be for a /color postscript/
     printer. I chose HP Color Laserjet 4550 PS
   - Set the printer port to RPT1: (the redirected port)
3. Configure the port
   Redirect Port to: "C:\gs\gs8.11\bin\gswin32c.exe"
   (Update this line to reflect your version and location of
   Ghostscript, if different)

Arguments for this program are:
@c:\gs\pdfconf.txt -sOutputFile="%1" -c .setpdfwrite -f -

Output: "Prompt for filename"
Run: "Normal"

1. Try printing something in color to this printer. If everything works
   right, you will be prompted for a filename that the PDF file will be
   saved under (Don't forget to add the .PDF extension).
   '
   Hope this helps someone!

CyranoVR@gmail.com